# Is the median score greater than 5?

Tags: statistical-significance

A consumer group rated 12 manufactured products
import
ed from a single
source on a scale
of 1 to 10. The data are shown below. Do the data provide sufficient evidence to
indicate tha
t the median score is greater than 5? Use
the
sign test at the 1% level of significance.

2
9
6
7
8
5
10
2
8
5
3
4

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I was never taught the sign test, so I do not know where to even start this question

Comment: There's intuition and an explanation [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rsignrank.pdf#page=5). If you're still have some trouble after looking at this, expand on where you're hitting the wall.

Comment: This looks like homework. If so, it should have the `self study` tag.

Comment: @Dimitriy I'm certainly having trouble with this, because the [sign test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test) as conventionally understood is designed to compare two samples drawn randomly from continuous distributions, rather than comparing one set of data (*not* a random sample and from a discrete distribution, no less) to a constant.  It's not immediately clear whether any of the natural attempts to apply the sign test in this situation would be valid.  Is there perhaps a more obviously applicable test that is also called "the sign test"?

Comment: @whuber Perhaps I missed the point, but there are plenty of presentations of the one sample version as 'the sign test'  - if many books do it, it's hard to say it's unconventional. The sign test on paired samples is equivalent to a one-sample sign test on a single sample. The link you point to has $Z_i = \text{sign}(Y_i - X_i)$ but that's identical to $W_i = Y_i - X_i$ and $Z_i= \text{sign}(W_i-0)$, a one sample sign test on $W$. That works even if $W_i$ weren't from paired data. Both the paired and one sample versions extend to $Z_i= \text{sign}(W_i-\stackrel{\sim}{\mu})$, as is done here.

Comment: Glen_b put it much better than I could.

Comment: ERocket - On the test itself, it's obvious at a glance that the null wouldn't be rejected at the 5% level let alone the 1%. Googling on *one sample sign test*; I see plenty of good hits on that phrase on the first page. The more fruitful avenue might be to find out where you were expected to know it from and read that.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you, but I am still not convinced of the applicability to this situation, for which $Z_i$ is discrete: at a minimum, the usual accounts of the test need to be modified to handle the ties at $5$. The issue is further confounded by dubious assertions made by some of the top Google hits on your search: [the #1 hit](http://www.unm.edu/~marcusj/1Samplesign.pdf), for instance, begins by asserting the sign test applies only to non-normal distributions! I posted that comment primarily to point out that there may be a bit more substance to this question than initially appears.

Comment: @whuber You're absolutely right that there's a problem with the discreteness. The direct applicability of the paired test in that case has the same problem of course, and at the least requires the same modification in that situation. Conditioning on the non-zero differences is the usual approach, but requires a little thought about how to relate the null hypothesis to what is being tested. On google: We won't see the same order since google tunes searches for individuals and locations (Wikipedia is my #1 for that search), and certainly not every hit I got is a good resource.

Comment: @Glen_b re Google, I hear you.  (But it was amusing that any top hit on such an incredibly simple procedure could be so woefully misleading.)

Comment: @whuber Yesterday I was considering writing an answer to this question that describes the sign test and how it works for both paired data and univariate data, including dealing with ties (since I saw they were present in the data in the question). I hesitated because it might take a while. However, it might be nice to have a more trustworthy resource here (since all my errors would be pointed out).

Answer (score 3):

The sign test is the name of two related location tests, suitable respectively for paired and single samples from continuous distributions.

The paired test is the more common, but the calculations are essentially the same for both.

In the case of the paired test, the usual hypothesis being considered is that $H_0: P(X-Y>0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

We also have a one-sample test by considering the differences $Z = X-Y$ as a single sample, which is then a test of whether the population median of $Z$ is zero. We don't even need the $Z$'s to be differences.

This is readily extended to a test of a general median (consider $Z=Z^*-\stackrel{\sim}{\mu_0}$ - a test for $Z$ having zero median is the same as a test for $Z^*$ having median $\mu_0$; and the paired test can be extended to testing for a specified shift in the same manner.)

So in each of the mentioned cases, our test boils down to testing $H_0:P(Z>0)=\frac{1}{2}$. The small sample test statistic is the count of observations where $Z>0$, which if the null hypothesis is true, has a binomial distribution with $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and $n$ the sample size (number of observations in one sample, or the number of pairs in the paired case). The alternative may be one or two tailed as required.

It can equivalently be treated as a proportions test (which is a scaled binomial), and in large samples reduces to the usual one sample Z-test of proportions.

(Further, testing other quantiles than the median is a matter of choosing the relevant proportion.)

---

**Ties**

Under the original assumption of continuity, no ties are possible.

If we have ties (such as $X_i=Y_i$,$Z^*_i=\stackrel{\sim}{\mu_0}$,or $Z_i=0$), then the distribution of the test statistic is no longer as stated.

The most common advice seems to be to throw out the ties, but we have to take care; that's potentially suitable in some situations but not in others.

Consider a two-tailed test - if we condition on $Z\neq 0$ we can get a test statistic that has a binomial distribution (with $n$ correspondingly reduced), but if we reject the null, that doesn't of itself imply the median is not 0, only that the *conditional median* is not zero. It's quite possible to reject the null and have the actual population median be zero!
When ties are possible, one must take care when considering what one is actually testing.

(We might be concerned, then, that the most common advice on how to deal with ties in this test is potentially flawed; in some cases it rescues the distribution of test statistic at the expense of the hypothesis! However, if the null is not rejected in the reduced case, it should also not be rejected in the unconditional case.)

The original hypothesis relating to the median can be rescued, however, without resort to computing permutations of signs.

Consider the distribution of $B =\text{sign}(Z)$, with $p_+ + p_0 + p_- = 1$. If we were to test both $p_+\leq\frac{1}{2}$ and $p_-\leq\frac{1}{2}$ (against alternatives that they're $>\frac{1}{2}$) at the $\alpha/2$ level and neither rejected, we would have failed to reject the null that the median was 0.

(The one-tailed equivalent would be to perform just one of those two tests, at level $\alpha$.)

---

**The problem in the question**:

This is a one-tailed test, so we can actually proceed with it without much difficulty, as long as we take a little care with the null.

The stated alternative is that $\stackrel{\sim}{\mu}>5$; in this case we can actually take the null to be the complement.

Now the test statistic: if the number of cases where $Z^*_i>5$ is higher than could be expected from a $\text{Bin}(n,\frac{1}{2})$ we can reject.

(One can see that 6 of 12 values exceed 5; clearly we won't reject at any sensible significance level; it wasn't even necessary for me to count them when I made my earlier comment about seeing at a glance we wouldn't reject since I could see without counting it was close to half.)